# How can I retrieve Stock data for multiple brands?

Tags: r, finance, stock

I am trying to collect data for my thesis. In my dataset I have:

- Company names (around ca. 90 company)
- Company Tweets
- Date of the Tweets
- Stock Symbol of the companies

In separate columns, I would like to add the stock price for that specific date in order to conduct an event study - however, all of the material that I find online looks at only one company. As a first step, I want to collect all the stock data from these companies in the period (which is 2 years), and then connect the two datasets. I have used the code:

```
stock_data <- getSymbols( tweet_stock_merge$`Stock Symbol`, src= "yahoo", from = "2019-12-26", to = "2022-01-06")
```

This provides me with the stock prices, however, in several datasets for each of them - is there a way I can retrieve the data in one dataset?

Thanks so much in advance, I hope it is clear what I intend to do, and it makes sense in general - it could also be that I am on the wrong track.

After the code: stock_data <- getSymbols( tweet_stock_merge$`Stock Symbol`, src= "yahoo", from = "2019-12-26", to = "2022-01-06")

I have looked online (including ChatGPT and RTutor), I have came up with the following code:

```
 # Create a new column in the df data frame
df$stock_price <- NA

# Create a loop to iterate through the date levels
for (date in levels(df$date)) {
  
  # Create a subset of the df data frame for each date level
  df_date <- subset(df, date == date)
  
  # Create a loop to iterate through the stock symbols
  for (stock_symbol in levels(df_date$stock_symbol)) {
    
    # Get the stock price for the stock symbol in the date level
    stock_price <- get_stock_price(date, stock_symbol)
    
    # Update the stock_price column in the df data frame
    df$stock_price[df$date == date & df$stock_symbol == stock_symbol] <- stock_price
  }
```

However, it did not provide me any real result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use quantmod and tidyquant to collect stock data for multiple companies and store it in a single dataset. Here's a way to do that. Load libraries
`quantmod` and `tidyquant`. Next, you define your stock symbols by using your own list of symbols from the `tweet_stock_merge` dataset). For example:

```
stock_symbols <- c("AAPL", "GOOGL", "MSFT")
start_date <- "2019-12-26"
end_date <- "2022-01-06"
stock_data <- tq_get(stock_symbols, from = start_date, to = end_date, adjust = TRUE)
tweet_stock_merge$Date <- as.Date(tweet_stock_merge$Date)
stock_data$date <- as.Date(stock_data$date)
merged_data <- merge(tweet_stock_merge, stock_data, by.x = c("Stock Symbol", "Date"), by.y = c("symbol", "date"), all.x = TRUE)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much, it worked! Such a huge help!